# Applying a patch that modifies multiple files

Tags: c++, diff, patch, git-diff

Im trying to apply the patch here, I's saving it as xLoader.patch

http://gitorious.org/x-load-omap3/mainline/commit/ee120c894c3377054bda149748eb0621f2f843c8?format=patch

It modifies more than one file and just won't go over smoothly from the base dir, I'm using the command below and getting a bunch of errors about hunks failing, how do I correctly do this? Is there a way to break up the file into segments that handle each file independently?

patch -p1 --dry-run -i xLoader.patch

Errors:

```
x-loader$ patch -p1 --dry-run -i xLoader-512_patch.txt
patching file board/omap3beagle/omap3beagle.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 310 (offset 45 lines).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 305.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file board/omap3beagle/omap3beagle.c.rej
patching file drivers/k9f1g08r0a.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 221 (offset 67 lines).
Hunk #2 FAILED at 185.
1 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file drivers/k9f1g08r0a.c.rej
patching file include/asm/arch-omap3/mem.h
Hunk #2 FAILED at 72.
Hunk #3 succeeded at 305 (offset 52 lines).
Hunk #4 succeeded at 364 (offset 52 lines).
1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file include/asm/arch-omap3/mem.h.rej
```

Comment: What are some of the errors you're actually getting? Are you sure you're applying it to the same base code that it was generated from?

Comment: From that, it seems that you are indeed trying to apply it to a different state of the code from that which the patch was generated from. I don't know your circumstances, but if you can generate the patch from the same code that you're trying to apply it on, that would certainly fix your problem.

Comment: Here is one of the functions and the rejects that are happening to it. http://pastebin.com/s0y8HAyj

Comment: From that, it would appear that your greatest problem is that you have whitespace inconsistencies for some reason. Pastebin converts everything to spaces, so I can't tell from it, but you're probably mixing spaces and tabs in weird and inconsistent ways between the various versions you're working on, and that's the patches won't apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all you need, then yes, it is possible to split it up into a segment for each file it patches. Just split it on the `---`/`+++` header lines. Each of those segments works perfectly well as an independent patch file.

Comment: I believe the diff for each file actually starts on the 'diff' line that's right before the "---" line.

Comment: Nah, the `diff` line and the one following it are simply ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using git and applying to a git working directory, you can use git-apply instead of patch.

It sounds like your patch just doesn't apply cleanly. There's no real need to apply it to only one file at a time, it will apply to the files it applies cleanly to, and save rejects for the files that fail.

You could split it into pieces if you wanted to, each separate file starts with a line with the 'diff' command.

If you're using GNU patch, there's a "-U" option that makes it save the reject files in unified diff instead of a normal diff. If you're used to reading unified diffs, this will make your life a lot easier when it comes time to manually apply the rejected hunks.

Another option is to create different git branches, one that the patch applies cleanly to, and one with whatever your changes are that make it not apply cleanly. Then merge the branch with the patch applied onto your own patch. That will probably give you inline diff3 style merge conflicts instead of .rej files.